# CHECK_NRPE Could not connect to…: Connect reset by peer in Nagios NRPE

Tags: nagios

CHECK_NRPE gives me the following error:

```
  [root@localhost libexec]# ./check_nrpe -H 172.30.85.218
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not connect to 172.30.85.218: Connection reset by peer
```

I dont see what is the problem here. I tried the installation several times. Firewall is off, but that shouldn't be the problem. Haven't found the error anywhere else. What am I missing? Thanks

```
vi /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,172.30.85.218,172.30.85.210
server_address=172.30.85.218/23

/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe
 service nrpe
  {
          disable = no
          flags           = REUSE
          type            = UNLISTED
          port            = 5666
          socket_type     = stream
          wait            = no
          user            = nagios
          group           = nagios
          server          = /usr/sbin/nrpe
          server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
          log_on_failure  += USERID
         only_from        = 127.0.0.1, 172.30.85.218
  }

[root@localhost libexec]# netstat -at | egrep "nrpe|5666"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:nrpe            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:nrpe               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Comment: Hello, did you check the `/var/log/messages` for any clues?

Comment: Apr 28 16:30:41 localhost nrpe[75649]: Error: (use_ssl == false): Request packet version was invalid!
 Apr 28 16:30:41 localhost nrpe[75649]: Could not read request from client 127.0.0.1, bailing out...
 Apr 28 16:30:41 localhost check_nrpe[75647]: Error: (nerrs = 0)(!log_opts) Could not complete SSL handshake with 127.0      .0.1: rc=-1 SSL-error=5
 Apr 28 16:34:29 localhost nrpe[75813]: Host 172.30.85.218 is not allowed to talk to us!
 Apr 28 16:34:29 localhost check_nrpe[75811]: Error: (nerrs = 0)(!log_opts) Could not complete SSL handshake with 172.3      0.85.218: rc=-1 SSL-error=5

Comment: Apr 28 16:35:39 localhost systemd[1]: Started Session 31 of user root.
 Apr 28 16:35:39 localhost systemd-logind[1210]: New session 31 of user root.

Comment: As you can see `Could not complete SSL handshake` you are probably running NRPE with SSL and your client is not configured in that way. Check `./check_nrpe --help` how to use SSL if needed.